# Crackling Sound Error - How do I limit available RAM

Tags: sound, ram, soundcard

When I had Windows 7 I had to limit the available RAM to 3GB maximum or I'd get crackling sound whenever a sound tried to play. Something to do with the drivers for the `Creative X-Fi` sound card.

Now that I've changed over to Ubuntu the sound has started crackling again.

Mightn't there be a way to limit the available RAM like I had to on Win7? Or I have to buy a new sound card?

Comment: That sounds like a pretty inconvenient limitation. I'd be looking for a better fix for the crackling, such as upgrading motherboard firmware, and the sound card driver, etc.  I don't think there's a guarantee that limiting RAM would have the same effect as on Windows, but it might.

Answer (score 0):

You can control this with kernel parameters. If you follow the prompt to edit your Grub menu items when you first boot you can add parameters.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/static/linux-kernel-parameters.php

The `mem` and `max_addr` parameters would seem to be the most relevant.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically limit RAM to 3GB you would :

**1)** Restart your system, or shut it down and then power it on again.

**2)** Press and hold down the SHIFT key immediately and keep it held down while the system starts to boot, in order to force the "GNU GRUB" menu to appear. The "GNU GRUB" menu will look something like this:

[image: grubimg]

**3)** Once the "GNU GRUB" menu appears, release SHIFT and then press the e key to enter edit mode. The edit mode screen screen will look something like this:

[image: grubeditimg]

**4)** Use the down arrow key to move the cursor to the line beginning with the word "linux", then cursor over to the end of the line where you see the kernel parameters. Normally this will be just after the words like "quiet splash vt_handoff".

**5)** Press SPACE to add a blank space (at the end of the line then carefully type in the kernel boot parameter that you need to add. In your case that will be `mem=3G`(Note that if you need to add multiple parameters separate them with SPACE but **do not add** spaces before or after any `=` signs or punctuation in the parameters themselves).

**6)** Press Ctrl+X to boot the system and test the parameters you've added.

Once you've confirmed you ahve the results that you want you can make these changes permanent by editing `/etc/default/grub` with your favorite text editor and adding the new kernel parameter to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line between the existing quotes preserving the existing parameters as needed.

Sources:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt